# Django - Caught ValueError while rendering: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have category field in my form:

```
category  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all().filter(parentCat=None),
                        widget = forms.Select(attrs = { 
                                                      'onchange' : "catChanged(this);", 
                                       )
                                                )              
                                                   }
```

before I added a filter, all was fine.  Then I added a filter to query all the categories that have parentCat = None.  I now get this error:

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Caught ValueError while rendering: list.remove(x): x not in list

Error is on the template where category field is rendered:  {{ form.category }}

```
<div style="position:relative" >   <label> {{ form.category.label }}:</label> {{ form.category }}</div>
```

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

update:
Strange behavior.  First time, GET renders the form, all is well; if I refresh, the second time GET renders the form I get the above error.  TO reproduce, I have to stop and restart the web server!

Comment: I imagine it's a formatting issue, but you are missing a closing "}" in the forms.Select(...)

Comment: I figured some work around - error was in backends.py - apparenlty non-rel for appengine has an issue with ForiegnKeys that are null - the failing line was :

query.table_map[table_name].remove(alias)

I added a try: and pass for exception - all seems to work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be a bug in Django or query adaptation by non-rel.

The error occured in  module backends.py - 
apparenlty there is an issue with querying for ForiegnKeys that are null -

the failing line was :

```
query.table_map[table_name].remove(alias)
```

I changed it to

```
try:
  query.table_map[table_name].remove(alias)
except:
  pass
```

This change basically ignores any errors in that line.
All works as expected now; although I'm not sure why the error occurred, this change seems to fix it.